# Java: Generic class compare method

Tags: java, generics, comparison

I am new to Java. Basically, I created my own generic Heap data structure that will accept any type of objects. And the Heap data structure contains a method that compares 2 objects like this: `heap[ parent(i)] <= heap[i]`. Obviously, this will cause an error because I cannot use `<=` to compare two objects.

**Question 1:** I need to write a method to replace `<=` such that if I pass in any two objects it will automatically do the equivalent of the `<=` comparison . But I do not know how to do so.

```
class Heap<E>{
      E[] heap;
      // constructor
      public Heap(E[] heap){
          this.heap = heap;
      }

      public int parent(int i){
          return  (int) Math.floor(i/2.0);
      }   
      ...

      // This is where the problem occurs    
      public boolean minHeapProperty(){
          for(int i = 0; i < heap.length; i++){
             // <= operator need to be replaced by a method can be used for comparison by all objects
             if( !( heap[ parent(i) ] <= heap[i] )){
                 return false;
             }
          }
          return true;
       }

    ........
}
```

**Question 2:** I have another object class `Vertex` and I am trying to write a method to compare 2 `Vertex` objects by an instance variable `node`. But I kept failing. **Note that I will be creating a heap of `Vertex` objects later on. So, I really only need a unique comparison method that can be used in both the `Heap` generic class and the `Vertex` class.** This is why two questions are related and I do not want to post two separate questions on this website.

```
  Vertex{
     public int node;

     public Vertex(int node){
        this.node = node;
     }

     // compare two vertex objects (I do not know how to write this in the right way)
     public boolean compareTwoVertexObjects(Vertex v2){
         // need an answer here. 
         return (node <= v2.node);    
     }
  }
```

Comment: Have all possible classes used implement `Comparable<T>` and then use the `compareTo(T other)` method.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you modify the type of `E` to specify that it must be [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) like

```
class Heap<E extends Comparable<E>>
```

then you can compare two instances `a` and `b` like

```
E a;
E b;
// ...
int c = a.compareTo(b);
if (c < 0) {
  // a < b
} else if (c > 0) {
  // a > b
} else {
  // a == b
}
```

Then you might modify `Vertex` to also be `Comparable` with something like

```
class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex> {
    public int node;

    public Vertex(int node) {
        this.node = node;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Vertex o) {
        return Integer.valueOf(node).compareTo(o.node);
    }
}
```

Comment: How come a generic object `E` can extend an interface ? I thought interface can only be implemented but not extend

Comment: @mynameisJEFF An interface extends another interface. This is how [generics](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/generics-tutorial-159168.pdf) were implemented as an add-on in Java 5. The language did not have generics initially.

Comment: The meaning of `extends` in this context is slightly different from the meaning of `extends` in a class or interface definition.  When you use it with a type parameter (that is, the `E` or `T` that's commonly used in a generic), it means "is a subtype of" - in other words, it either _extends_ the type OR _implements_ the type OR is the type itself.  This is so that you can use `E` to substitute for either a class or an interface.

Comment: Is there a difference using between `E` and `T` ? Or they are just the same thing ? Because I seen others symbols like `?` and I am not entirely sure what they all mean ?

Comment: That sounds like a new question.

Comment: @mynameisJEFF You should read up on generics. `?` is known as a [`Wildcard capture`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html). As for `E` and `T` they can be anything; also common are `K` and `V` (see `Map`, where they are Key and Value).

Comment: for best results use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`